# Beta profile fit of Virgo cluster gas?

Tags: cosmology, gas, galaxy-cluster

I'm looking for the parameters $r_c$, $\rho_0$ and $\beta$ in a $\beta$-profile fit of the Virgo cluster's ICM density. I just can't find a reference for it. Unlike for Coma (Abell 1656) where it's in Mohr et. al. 1999.

Beta profile:

$$\rho(r) = \rho_0 \left[ 1+ \left(\frac{r}{r_c}\right)^2 \right]^{-\frac{3\beta}{2}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Schindler et al. 1999](http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9811464v1.pdf): Morphology of the Virgo Cluster: Gas versus Galaxies has details for $\beta$ model fits for Virgo and its subclusters.